# On which WAS port does the EAR listen on?

Tags: websphere, port, ear

If I deploy an EAR on WAS 6.1 and I want to use a remote ejb client, i need to know the url.

Now I know the host name where the EAR is deployed but i need the port number also. On WAS console when i go to Ports,  I see many ports running different services. Which one is the one on which the EAR is listening?

Is it the one marked BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS?

Comment: This document indicates that it is indeed the BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0310_alcott/alcott.html  What happens when you try that one?

Comment: Thanks man. When i do that, the look up returns null (not NPE)instead of a remote interface :(. I verified the EAR is running properly. This returns nul:(IntegrationServiceRemote) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(initialContext.lookup(IntegrationServiceRemote.class.getName()), IntegrationServiceRemote.class);